# How to dynamically show or hide form fields depending on the state of a BooleanInput field in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-admin

I need to build a complex edit form with react-admin. The form has a variety of yes/no sliders made with the BooleanInput component of react-admin. 
If the user sets the slider to "yes", further form fields should appear dynamically, which refer thematically to the slider. How do I query the status of the BooleanInput component or would this task be solved in react in a different way?

```
<BooleanInput source="yesno" label="show or hide fields" />
<AutocompleteArrayInput source="probably_hidden1" label="show or hide me" choices={[
        { id: 'one', name: '1' },
        { id: 'two', name: '2' },
        { id: 'three', name: '3' }
]} />
<TextInput multiline source="text" label="show or hide me too" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out: It can be done using FormDataConsumer like this:

```
<BooleanInput source="yesno" label="show or hide fields" />
<FormDataConsumer>
    {({ formData, ...rest }) => formData.yesno && <div>
        <AutocompleteArrayInput source="yesno" label="show or hide fields" choices={[
            { id: 'one', name: '1' },
            { id: 'two', name: '2' },
            { id: 'three', name: '3' }
        ]} {...rest} />
        <TextInput multiline source="text" label=""show or hide me too" {...rest} />
    </div>
    }
</FormDataConsumer>
```

See:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#hiding-inputs-based-on-other-inputs

Answer (score 1):

You could write dynamically code inside JSX

```
> { isShow ? <TextInput ... /> : null }
```

Comment: I'm quite new to react and JSX. Where can I put code inside JSX tags?

Comment: Inside the return of your render method
`<div>
{ You can write JavaScript Code Here }
<p>Hello</p
</div>
`

Comment: thanks, but where does BooleanInput stores it's value?

Comment: You have Two options for that, (Hooks,Classes).

I'll give u an example for hooks ( you should read about it ).
Hooks give u an option to save state in a functional component, s
`const [boolValue, setBoolValue] = useState(false)
<input onChange={ (event) => setBoolValue(event.target.value) }
`